# How to create empty array in router.get?

Tags: json, express

I'm trying to make something like that.

```
{
    suggestions: [{
        "nameClient": "John",
        "nameFantasyClient": "smachs"
    }, {
        "nameClient": "José",
        "nameFantasyClient": "apoch"
    }]
}
```

Can not find anything about how to make empty array. This is a return i am receiving to my api  /product/sell/name-of-client-search.

```
[
    {
        "nameClient": "John",
        "nameFantasyClient": "smachs"
    },
    {
        "nameClient": "José",
        "nameFantasyClient": "apoch"
    }
]
```

This my router.get responsible for extracting data from the database and sending it to front-end.

```
router.get('/product/sell/name-of-client-search', function (req, res) {
  connection.query('SELECT nameClient,nameFantasyClient FROM new_client',
    function (err, nameOfClientToSell, fields) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      res.send(nameOfClientToSell);
    }
  );
});
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the json on the fly.

```
router.get('/product/sell/name-of-client-search', function (req, res) {
  connection.query('SELECT nameClient,nameFantasyClient FROM new_client',
    function (err, nameOfClientToSell, fields) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      res.send({ suggestions: nameOfClientToSell });
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Working, Thanks ;D